# Can't set background color in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, macos-catalina

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def myClick():
    myLabel = Label(root, text='Button clicked. ')
    myLabel.pack()

myButton = Button(root, text="Click me!", command=myClick, fg='blue', background="red", activeforeground='green', activebackground='black')


myButton.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The code runs fine except the background color. Could someone help? Many thanks
BTW, I'm using Python 3.7.4 and macOS Catalina 10.15.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why aren't these tkinter stylings working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58343068/why-arent-these-tkinter-stylings-working)

Comment: The code works fine for me on Windows 10 (1909) and Python 3.8 using Pycharm.

Comment: You can't change the background color of buttons on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

On python 3.8 and windows 7 at least is work fine. Style can work to, but with what u set is text color blue and background red, when the button is pressed the text will become green and the background black.